# Brasero says no enough room on CD

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, cd, brasero

I am trying to burn some mp3s to a CD using Brasero.

According to thunar, I have 717 Mb of songs.

But Brasero says the project is 737 Mbs and asks if I want to use multiple disks.

I used the create data option.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are assuming that Thunar and Brasero are in conflict in measuring the size of the data.

In fact, they are both right.

This has to do with the way that data is stored in blocks on a disk. If you have a file with 1 byte of content, it will still take up a whole block of space (generally 1024 bytes).  Similarly if you have a file with 1025 bytes of content, it will actually take up two blocks or 2048 bytes.

Different applications use different algorithms to estimate the size of data.

In the case of Brasero, you are getting this error because there truly is not enough space on the disk for the data you have asked it to burn. You will need to leave something out, or otherwise reduce the size of the data you want to write to CD.

FYI: an audio project will definitely be too large because MP3s would be converted to a raw format which takes up a lot more space. This is why audio CDs can only play ~80 min.

Comment: Ok. I decided to burn one less file and Brasero accepted it and did a successful burn.